# MySQL Include a script within script

Tags: sql, mysql, scripting

I'm involved is a project to migrate a project from Oracle to MySQL. In Oracle I have the ability to create a SQL script that references or inlcudes other external SQL script files when the batch is run via command line. I Have a script called CreateAllTables.sql that looks like this internally:

```
@tables\Site.sql
@tables\Language.sql
@tables\Country.sql
@tables\Locale.sql
@tables\Tag.sql
```

I'm already aware of the MySQL command line "Source" command, but my goal is to invoke a single main .sql script file that includes other scripts via one single command line call like this:

```
mysql --user=root --password --database=junkdb -vv < CreateAllTables.sql
```

So my question is how do I do this with MySQL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`source` works for me.

```
# -- foo.sql
DROP TABLE foo;
source bar.sql

# -- bar.sql
CREATE TABLE bar (i INT NOT NULL);

$ mysql ... < foo.sql
```

Now table *foo* is gone and *bar* is created.

Comment: +1 Interesting, all of the examples I saw seemed to suggest this was a command line function only. I'm still pretty new to MySQL.

Comment: @James, you're right, the `mysql(1)` man page does strongly suggest that this is an interactive-mode command only.

Comment: You can do 

help 

in the mysql command line client, and see the possible commands understood by the client (not sql server commands, mysql command line commands):

mysql> help

For information about MySQL products and services, visit:
   http://www.mysql.com/
For developer information, including the MySQL Reference Manual, visit:
   http://dev.mysql.com/
To buy MySQL Network Support, training, or other products, visit:
   https://shop.mysql.com/

List of all MySQL commands:
Note that all text commands must be first on line and end with ';'
?         (\?) Synonym for `help'.
...etc...

Comment: @avok00:  May I ask specifically what you mean that *"[t]his does not work in scripts"*?  The OP wanted a batch or scripted solution that used a "top-level" `.sql` file to include and execute other named `.sql` files.  That's precisely what I show.  With minor variation, that's also what [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1976496/132382) shows.

Comment: Yes and if you kindly try to run this top-level.sql with the source commands inside, you will find that it does nothing. And produces an error. That means it does not work. I resolved my very similar problem by doing a .bat file with multiple mysql command line tool calls inside. But it is not a SQL file, therefore not an answer to the original question too.

Comment: I'm sorry, @avok00, I _did_ run it and it works for me just as the OP's template suggests:  `mysql(1)` command line client, followed by input redirection of a single `.sql` file referencing other `.sql` files.  Perhaps you could post your .bat file (are you on Windows?), your SQL files and your error message in a new question, and S.O. can help you, too. :)

Comment: Does not work in MySQL Workbench 6.1, but does work from the command line on my Windows 8.1 installation.

Comment: how can w include that inside a trigger? to be included when the trigger is created not when it is lauched.

Answer (score 17):

Note that the "source" option, above, only works (for me) if the script is run through a mysql client that supports it.  (The mysql command-line client referenced in the OP's original question happens to be one of those clients.)

But remember "source" is **not** one of the many mysql-specific extensions to the sql language.  It's a client-command, not a sql statement,

Why do you care?

If you're sending your sql script to the MySQL server via an alternative method (via JDBC's "execSQL", for example) the "source" command will not work for the inclusion of other scripts.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yah, I know.  I would have preferred to simply add a comment to the accepted answer's comment list.  There is some confusion in that comment stream and I thought this info would help clarify.  But this is a new stackoverflow account and I don't yet have enough cred to comment. (At least I think that's why I can't comment.).  So I just posted a new "clarifying" answer instead.  Apologies if this offends.

Answer (score 8):

You can do a similar thing with source in mysql.

I have inc1.sql with these contents:

```
use test;
create table testinc(
   id int  
);
```

And inc2.sql like this:

```
insert into testinc values (1);
```

and main.sql like this:

```
source inc1.sql
source inc2.sql
```

And i can run main.sql like this:

```
mysql -uroot -pmysql -P3351 -e"Source main.sql"
```

After that I can verify that it worked by doing this:

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> select * from testinc;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```