# How to include files with MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This MSE [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976396/mysql-include-a-script-within-script) is very closely related, but I couldn't find the answer to my particular question here.

I wish to accomplish the following simple task : write a file main.sql so that, when it’s imported by phpMyAdmin, simply imports four files called create1.sql, create2.sql, create3.sql and create4.sql.

I tried writing the following into main.sql :

```
source create1.sql;
source create2.sql;
source create3.sql;
source create4.sql;
```

But the above doesn't work, I get the following error message :

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only in a command line ;)

Comment: And there’s no way to tell phpMyAdmin in a file "Please import those following .sql files" ? There’s no MySQL command for this ?